# Android SQL cursor is NULL

Tags: android, sql, null, indexoutofboundsexception

In my sql.query, there are times when the cursoe should return a null value.  For example in the below code, the cursor is seeking a username. If the User has a username, then the cursor will return it.  If not then I assume it is null.  My problem is that when a cursor does find a null value, then I get a crash with an "out of bounds" error.  Basically means the cursor did not find anything.

```
   public static String getUserName() {

        int rowIncrement = 1; 
        Log.d(DATABASE, "Getting Username");
        String[] usercolumns = new String[] { KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD };
        Cursor c = myDatabase.query(USER_TABLE, usercolumns, KEY_ROWID + "="
                + rowIncrement, null, null, null, null);
        if (c != null) {
            c.moveToFirst();
            String lUserName = c.getString(1);
            Log.d("DATABASE", "Username = " + lUserName);
            return lUserName;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

What is wrong with this code that would cause a crash if the cursor does not find anything?

Comment: please post the logcat output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems because of `c.moveToFirst()` returns boolean. So you should change your code like this.

```
if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        String lUserName = c.getString(1);
        Log.d("DATABASE", "Username = " + lUserName);
        return lUserName;
    }
```

You can check this here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html

Comment: still not quite right.  I am getting a null pointer exception now.  In this instance there is purposely no username in the table.  The user should be redirected to the account creation page based on this fact, but since the value which is returned is "null" then the app crashes.

Comment: Actually wait, the string condition was incorrect on the return side.  I had if{fUsername.isempty   instead of  if{fUsername == null